# Recording of Visits from Mobile Browsers (Opera Mini)

Tags: bug

Just noticed that visits to Stack overflow from mobile devices (Opera Mini) are not recorded on the profile pages.

Is this by design, if so why?

Comment: What makes you think that is the case? (Not saying it's not; just looking for some clarification)\

Comment: How have you determined that? Did you wait for the cache to clear?

Comment: When I visit the site on my smartphone over the weekends and holidays, the consecutive visit counter on my account does not increment, however on my desktop browser it does. I am currently logged into both all the time hence the question.

Comment: But have you given the cache time to clear (I believe it is 10 minutes on the profile page)

Comment: @Oded I do not understand what you mean, over the weekend I do not use my laptop only my smartphone so I am sure that is enough time for the cache to clear on either device. What is clear is that visits from the smartphone browser are not recorded ... How do you suggest I try it out?

Comment: @ssmusoke - Thanks for clarifying. It certainly is enough time.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but when you browse with the smartphone do you visit any other pages than the front page? Hitting only the front page doesn't increment the visit counter.

Comment: @Juhana yes I visit other pages, on the site (I usually go to unanswered questions). Strange enough in my tests on the desktop browser it increments the counter if you just visit and refresh the profile page (for each section of the site). I spent some time testing out different scenarios before I posted here

Comment: @AndrewBarber sorry I had not responded to your question earlier - its based on my observations and I know Stack Exchange does many things that are not conventional but have "logic" so I am trying to understand the thinking behind this one.